# How do I ensure that as part of maven build process I upload the a newly created artifact automatically?

Tags: maven

How do I ensure that as part of maven build process I upload the a newly created artifact automatically ?

Let's say I have added a new maven module.
There's already a parent module for which I have added this as a child.
Now, we know that, this child module is not present in the repository.

Let's say that there is another module which refers to this child module while assembling a package, so it is going to refer to the repository and during the assembly, it will not find it.
for local testing, I did manage to upload to local repo using the mvn commands.
But the first time, I got unauthorized errors.

Comment: unauthorized means your configuration in your settings.xml related to distributionManagmenet is wrong / not correct...